# what is the significance of asp.net webpart controls in today applications?

Tags: asp.net

what is the significance of  asp.net webpart controls in today applications?

Where in we have AJAX,JQuery, MVC Controls are being used in today application.Does Webpart Controls still being used? Need to now know more detail in this regard.

Answer (score 1):

Webparts are still quite significant in the Sharepoint/intranet world. However outside of sharepoint I've not seen a lot of development take place around this particular piece of ASP.net.

Non-sharepoint/intranet applications, especially those applications that are public facing would do much better using AJAX/jquery and more open and widely used technologies. This is of course my opinion. But webparts are a little "heavy" for sites/applications that have to keep the general public in mind.

Answer (score 1):

One significance of WebParts is, that it isn't implemented in mono, meaning you can't port your code to non-windows platforms if you use them. Apart from that, now that ASP.NET finally has a MVC framework, I wouldn't use anything with a postback architecture.